# .htaccess Re-direct issue / Re-write rule conflict

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following code...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(css|js|admin|scripts|É)(/|$) - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$0 -d

RewriteRule ^[^/]+ - [L]

# Redirect .htm to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm /index.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\ /index.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Which works fine.

However I need to add 301 re-directs, so I added the folowing:

```
# Below are the re-directs needed.
Redirect 301 /oldlink.htm /newlink.htm
```

When I type in oldlink.htm however I get newlink.htm?name=oldlink&id=

Which isn't what I want, I need it to goto newlink.htm

Can anyone help?

Comment: Use `RewriteLog` to debug the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Avoid mixing mod_proxy and mod_rewrite
2. You will need a `RewriteCond` to prevent application of the rules after 301.
3. Your rules are not correct either.

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^oldlink\.htm$ /newlink.htm [L,R=301,NC]

# Redirect .htm to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html?$ /index.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(css|js|admin|scripts|É)/?$ - [L]

## DON'T KNOW WHAT THIS RULE IS DOING
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\ /index.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```